# unexpected behaviour with ConTeXt natural table headers height

Tags: tables, context

I am using TABLE to design map legends. I have trouble with the first row, where I am merging cells. Everything works as I expect when I use this code :

```
\starttext
%\setupTABLE[column][1,3][width=3em,align={middle,lohi}]
\setupTABLE[column][2,4][width=0.42 \textwidth,align=lohi]
\setupTABLE[row][first][align=flushleft]
\bTABLE
\bTR \bTH[nc=2] I. My first part \eTH \bTH[nc=2] II. My second part\eTH \eTR
\bTR \bTD sqr \eTD \bTD some text \eTD \bTD sqr \eTD \bTD some text \eTD \eTR
\eTABLE
```

[image: compilation 1]

However, if I uncomment the setup line for columns 1 and 3, I get unexpected and unwanted big vertical spaces in my first line.

```
\starttext
\setupTABLE[column][1,3][width=3em,align={middle,lohi}]
\setupTABLE[column][2,4][width=0.42 \textwidth,align=lohi]
\setupTABLE[row][first][align=flushleft]
\bTABLE
\bTR \bTH[nc=2] I. My first part \eTH \bTH[nc=2] II. My second part\eTH \eTR
\bTR \bTD sqr \eTD \bTD some text \eTD \bTD sqr \eTD \bTD some text \eTD \eTR
\eTABLE
```

[image: compilation 2]

I can't understand why. Deleting the align option does not change anything. What should I do, and where does this unexpected behaviour come from ?

Comment: You could still force the height of the first row to some sensible value, e.g. `\setupTABLE[row][first][align=flushleft,height=4ex]
`

Comment: @DG' that fixes it. Could you turn your comment into an answer I will upvote? I would also accept it until someone explains this behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea, what happens with the height calculation of the first row, but you can force some sensible value, e.g. `4ex`:

```
\starttext
    \setupTABLE[column][1,3][width=3em,align={middle,lohi}]
    \setupTABLE[column][2,4][width=0.42 \textwidth,align=lohi]
    \setupTABLE[row][first][align=flushleft,height=4ex]

    \bTABLE
        \bTR \bTH[nc=2] I. My first part \eTH \bTH[nc=2] II. My second part\eTH \eTR
        \bTR \bTD sqr \eTD \bTD some text \eTD \bTD sqr \eTD \bTD some text \eTD \eTR
    \eTABLE
\stoptext
```

[image]

**EDIT**

You can of course switch to `xtables` which calculates the size of the table better:

```
\startxtable[option=stretch]
\startxtablehead
    \startxrow 
        \startxcell[nx=2] I. My first part   \stopxcell 
        \startxcell[nx=2] II. My second part \stopxcell 
    \stopxrow
\stopxtablehead
\startxtablebody
    \startxrow 
        \startxcell[width=3em,align={middle,lohi}] sqr \stopxcell 
        \startxcell[width=.4\textwidth] sometext \stopxcell     
        \startxcell[width=3em,align={middle,lohi}] sqr \stopxcell 
        \startxcell[width=.4\textwidth] sometext \stopxcell 
    \stopxrow
 \stopxtablebody
\stopxtable
```

[image]